# AzureVMStart for Specified VM's with Paralallel execution

Tags: azure-automation

```
$VMList = @{}

$VMList.Add("SECPREPRODFLEET", "CH-PRE-PROD-RG")
$VMList.Add("SECPREPRODLDAP1 ", "CH-PRE-PROD-RG")

#Getting the VM object using Get-AzureRmVM and then Starting the VMs

$VMList.Keys | % {Get-AzureRmVM -Name $_ -ResourceGroupName $VMList.Item($_)} | Start-AzureRmVM

#Write-Output "All the VMs have been Started successfully"
```

The above script is working good for me as I want to start specified VMs in a ResourceGroup. However, this is an sequential execution which is taking time to execute. How can I change the above script to a parallel job?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of implementing parallel processing in Azure Automation. You can start here: http://www.thinkingcloud.nl/azure-automation-and-parallel-processing.